# Grails complicated unique variable from list of repeated names

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

following from my other question [Grails query - can't access join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643491/grails-query-cant-access-join-table)

I now have a list of searchresults but I need to display each name and a select box for each parameter. I have a name and a value. The names have repetition, for example, color and clarity are repeated many times as in this example:

```
NAME    VALUE
Color   red          
Color   blue    
Color   green    
Clarity clear
Clarity turbid
Clarity hazy
```

I need a variable ${name} that would represent color or clarity to be printed once for each unique item in the name list. Also I need to generate a dropdown box that holds the values associated with the Name: IE

color values 
         red, 
         blue, 
         green

I am thinking I can use 'unique()' somewhere but I am not sure how to do it. Should I be looking at the controller or the gsp side?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it server/controller side and I would use the [Collection.groupBy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#groupBy%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method.  For example:

```
yourListOfStuff.groupBy {it.name}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am sure it will lead me in the right direction, however, I could not get it to work. It just ignores the groupby statement. ` //def list = SampleType.get(params['id']).sampleParameters.sort {it.name}
       //list.groupBy {it.name}` - I can get a set of both the names and values, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I ended up just using a hashmap in plain old java code and iterating over the set, then passing that to the gsp.